# Найти cookie по ключу

Tags: javascript, cookie

Есть массив `kWords = ['hello',2,'flour',5,'work',7,'set',9,11,12,14];`

В первой итерации скрипта записываю cookie со значением индекса переменной массива (после завершения скрипта):

```
document.cookie = `nameCoo=${num}`;
```

Во второй итерации пытаюсь найти значение по ключу, чтобы изменить индекс переменной массива и присвоить переменной следующее значение массива, но не могу вытащить значение.

```
function getCookie(nameCoo) {
  let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
if(btnSerh != null && num == getCookie(nameCoo)) {
    num = num + 1;
}
let kWord=kWords[num];
```

Как перезаписать переменную num ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  let match = document.cookie
     .split('; ')
     .find(row => row.startsWith(`${name}=`));
  
  return match ? match.split('=')[1] : undefined;
}

function setCookie(name, value) {
    document.cookie = `${encodeURIComponent(name)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
}

getCookie('nameCoo'); // undefined
setCookie('nameCoo', 1); // nameCoo=1
setCookie('nameCoo', 2); // nameCoo=2
getCookie('nameCoo'); // 2
```

Стоит отметить:

> Мы можем писать в document.cookie. Но это не просто данные, а акcессор (геттер/сеттер). Присваивание обрабатывается особым образом.
> Запись в document.cookie обновит только упомянутые в ней куки, но при этом не затронет все остальные.
> https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]